# How to pass information from client to bot framework composer directly and pick that value in composer?

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I'm able to get email id and name through direct line token generation api, I also need to capture some additional information from the payload in direct line web client (eg.City) directly in composer.
How to capture those values in composer ?
In this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0 , mentioned as
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5ksR.png)
How to send those contents before directline sends conversation update ?